# Rails insert/ update missing a param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I am seeing this behavior for the first time. When making an insert the insert is missing one of the params. Here are my model and controller

**Model**

```
class Campaign < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :supplier
  has_many :campaign_offices
  has_many :campaign_plans
  has_many :campaign_plan_tiers
end
```

**Controller**

```
class CampaignsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :get_model, :only => [ :edit, :update, :destroy, :show ]

  def index
    @models = Campaign.order(:display_name)
  end

  def show

  end

  def create
    Campaign.create(model_params)
    redirect_to campaigns_path
  end

  def edit
    @models = Campaign.order(:display_name)
  end

  def update
    @model.update(model_params)
    redirect_to campaigns_path
  end

  def destroy
    @model.destroy
    redirect_to campaigns_path
  end


  private

  def get_model
    @model = Campaign.find(params[:id])
  end

  def model_params
    params.require(:campaign).permit( :display_name, :supplier_id, :campaign_code, :start_date, :end_date )
  end

end
```

And this is how the insert is working. This is a copy paste of the server logs on my local dev machine

```
Started POST "/campaigns" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-04-04 13:19:44 -0400
   (0.4ms)  SET NAMES utf8,  @@SESSION.sql_mode = CONCAT(CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',STRICT_ALL_TABLES'), ',NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'),  @@SESSION.sql_auto_is_null = 0, @@SESSION.wait_timeout = 2147483
   (0.2ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.`version` FROM `schema_migrations` ORDER BY `schema_migrations`.`version` ASC
Processing by CampaignsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"PA+xaH7ehMCNFB7+FfQ38KF2W07T7rGebj3rBQhJ6SLKqxyJTyTrES0qKDE5HWhEZ1x0p9vTO4Ur1qk4CYvPgQ==", "campaign"=>{"display_name"=>"Beat the heat", "campaign_code"=>"BTH-0293949", "supplier_id"=>"6", "start_date"=>"05/01/2018", "end_date"=>"05/31/2018"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Supplier Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `suppliers`.* FROM `suppliers` WHERE `suppliers`.`id` = 6 LIMIT 1
  **SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO `campaigns` (`display_name`, `supplier_id`, `campaign_code`, `start_date`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('Beat the heat', 6, 'BTH-0293949', '2018-01-05', '2018-04-04 17:19:44', '2018-04-04 17:19:44')**
   (0.8ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/campaigns
Completed 302 Found in 58ms (ActiveRecord: 3.9ms)
```

The end date is not making its way in either insert or update statements. It is being omitted. The column exists in db and migrations also have the column listed. I have also started the server but same thing. There are no callbacks in the model as well as evident from the model code pasted above.

**Environment is mysql, rails 5.1.6, ruby 2.4.0**

I have never seen this before. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: is it working for start_date?

Comment: Can you add the appropriate migration for the Campaign?

Comment: Can you how `campaigns` table looks like in `schema.rb` file. I have a feeling you don't have `end_date` column in the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the parameters for `start_date`, we see this:

```
"start_date"=>"05/01/2018"
```

and in the INSERT statement we see the `start_date` in ISO-8601 format:

```
'2018-01-05'
```

The input format is being interpreted as `DD/MM/YYYY`. If we look at the `end_date`, we see:

```
"end_date"=>"05/31/2018"
```

That's `MM/DD/YYYY` not `DD/MM/YYYY`. When your model tries to parse that as a date using the `DD/MM/YYYY` format, it gets nonsense and the date is ignored.

Your best bet is to use the ISO 8601 date format (`YYYY-MM-DD`) everywhere except for display. Fix the format in the client or, if necessary, in your controller.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was exactly the problem.